# How can I share a link to Google Maps with 3D view enabled?

Tags: google-maps, links, sharing

I can share a link to Google Maps with someone so that they can view the location from above:

https://www.google.com/maps/@42.213931,-8.7751829,46m/data=!3m1!1e3

And it looks like this:

[image]

Now, they could manually click on "Enable glove view":

[image]

And they would not only see a satellite image from above, but a 3D model of the map that, depending on the location, may even include 3D models of the houses, trees, etc.:

[image]

Is there any way I could create a link so that, when visited, the visitor would directly see the 3D view of the map instead of the satellite image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to **first click on the `3D` option** just above the global view.

You can **then copy the link**, which has now become

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@42.2135127,-8.7751829,51a,35y,39.61t/data=!3m1!1e3
```

Notice the change from `...-8.7751829,46m/...` to `...-8.7751829,51a,35y,39.61t/...`

[image]

---

**EDIT** *(following OP's [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/148086/how-can-i-share-a-link-to-google-maps-with-3d-view-enabled/148107#comment134686_148107))*

**Unfortunately you cannot force the users' browser to show on `3D`.

They have to choose it themselves**.

*That is the reason why it does not work on your incognito/other browser.*

Comment: The URL does change, but the link does not seem to always work. In example: try to open it in an incognito window, or in a different browser.

Comment: Please see the edited answer. As for your question *"How can I share a link to Google Maps with 3D view enabled?"*, I believe it is answered. If you want you could [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it or even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept :)

Comment: Thanks to you, for taking the time to answer. :-)

Comment: Based on the solution of marikamitsos I tried to force with the following link and for me it works: https://www.google.com/maps/@42.2135127,-8.7751829,51a,35y,39.61t/data=!3m1!1e3?force=webgl . I guess the problem is that in private mode and other browsers the 3D mode is even available?